# How do i get the BoxLayout to add widget if it's in another class?

Tags: python, kivy

so here is my Class

```
class CreateTask(Screen):
    def CreateTask(self, *args):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical",spacing=10)
        name=self.ids.TaskName.text
        desc=self.ids.TaskDesc.text
        bl.add_widget(name)
        bl.add_widget(desc)
        self.MainLayout.add_widget(bl)
```

and that is the kv of MainLayout

```
<SecondWindow>:
    name:"second"
    BoxLayout:
        id:MainLayout
        orientation:"vertical"
        Button:
            text:"Add Task"
            on_release:
                app.root.current="third"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
        Button:
            text:"Come Back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current ="main"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

it has to create widgets by clicking in the BoxLayout which is in another class. But when i run it i get "AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'" error, so how do i refer to the BoxLayout if it's in another class?
here is my .py file

```
from kivy.app import  App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import  BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import  AnchorLayout
Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass
class CreateTask(Screen):
    def CreateTask(self,*args):
        bl = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical",spacing=10)
        name=self.ids.TaskName.text
        desc=self.ids.TaskDesc.text
        lbl_name = Label(text=name)
        lbl_desc = Label(text=desc)
        bl.add_widget(lbl_name)
        bl.add_widget(lbl_desc)
        self.get_screen("second").ids.MainLayout.add_widget(bl)
class RegisterWindow(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

kv=Builder.load_file("mainscreen.kv")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainScreenApp().run()
```

Comment: If you want to access another screen then you might have to use `root.get_screen("screen_name").ids.widget_id`. Post full code in the right format if you want a more precise answer.

Comment: edited it, i tried to do root.get_screen("screen_name").ids.widget_id but i got an error root is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put instances of both the screens inside the screen manager to be able to access them. Put this in the .kv file:

```
<WindowManager>:
    CreateTask
    SecondWindow
```

Then edit this in the .py file:

```
self.get_screen("second").ids.MainLayout.add_widget(bl)
```

to:

```
self.root.get_screen("second").ids.MainLayout.add_widget(bl)
```

Here's the explaination:
Since you were calling self from a method of CreateTask class, it was referring to the instance of CreateTask class. I told you to put an instance of CreateTask class as well as SecondWindow class inside the WindowManager. So this makes WindowManager the root of both CreateTask and SecondWindow classes. Therefore with respect to CreateTask, the WindowManager would be `self.root`. Hence with respect to CreateTask class, SecondWindow would be `self.root.get_screen("second")`

Comment: yeah, i put all screens into the kv WindowManager but now  i get an error  AttributeError: 'CreateTask' object has no attribute 'root'

Comment: Is the method CreateTask inside the class CreateTask, supposed to be the constructor?